# Dynamic setting of net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name from json payload

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

In my jrxml the datasource is json we have a one field

```
{
  "sheetName":"test"
}
```

along with other json fields. When output of jasper report is in xlsx we want the sheet name to be value of this input json .

As per our understanding the sheet name for xlsx output from jrxml can be set by property setting "*net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name"

hence to provide this property value I declared this fields in main data set as

```
<field name="sheetName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="sheetName"/>
</field>
```

and thenI declare property expression to set dynamic set sheet name for jasperreport element like this

```
<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name"><![CDATA[$F{sheetName}]]></propertyExpression>
```

I still get value specified in `<jasperReport>` element.i.e sheet name in the generated xlsx file is the name of the report as specified for the report instead of value of net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name.

Is there way to set ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name*** from input json in jrxml?

in the below code by setting the property as part of jasperreport does not show the sheet name from json

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SheetNameTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1f31f952-cc6a-4faf-b8fd-2ede4119ea9f">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="modtest\dynamicSheet.xml"/>
    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name"><![CDATA[$F{sheetName}]]></propertyExpression>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="sheetName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="sheetName"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[sheetName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="259" y="38" width="100" height="30" uuid="653aa746-6763-4fbb-8576-cebe40169a8b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["JsonSheet"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="231" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

in the below code by setting the sheet name in text field displays the sheet name from json

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SheetNameTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1f31f952-cc6a-4faf-b8fd-2ede4119ea9f">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="modtest\dynamicSheet.xml"/>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="sheetName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="sheetName"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[sheetName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="259" y="38" width="100" height="30" uuid="653aa746-6763-4fbb-8576-cebe40169a8b">
                    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name"><![CDATA[$F{sheetName}]]></propertyExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["JsonSheet"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="231" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Solution work if the sheet name is specified in text field.

thanks
Anjana.

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: added more explanation on the question

Comment: has anyone come across  setting sheet name dynamically through JRXML

Comment: I tried this and I have no problem setting the sheetName from a field that use json as datasource, please add [mcve]

Comment: Thanks the issue is when "net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name " is set as propertyExpression on jasperReport  then dynamic sheet does not set however if it is set on text field then it consider sheet name from fields.  added code which works and code which does not work